# Library class doesn't know of ConfigureWebHostDefaults extension method

Tags: .net-standard-2.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm building a suite of *REST* micro-services using *.Net Core 3.0 Preview 6*.  All these services will have the same start up logic.  So, I'm trying to place all the code in a **.Net** Standard library.

The goal is to have the ***IHostBuilder:CreateHostBuilder*** method, as well as the ***Startup:Configure*** and ***Startup:ConfigureServices*** class and methods in the library.  The library will also contain error handling logic, customized *http* response messages, etc.

However, I can't seem to find the correct package that contains the ***ConfigureWebHostDefaults*** method.  I tried adding the ***Microsoft.AspNetCore package 2.2.0***, but that didn't resolve the issue.

I added the ***Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting (3.0.0-preview-6)*** package, that also doesn't resolve the issue.

Is what I'm attempting even possible?

Thanks

-marc

Comment: Have you tried adding v2.2.0 of `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`?

Comment: I can't add the 2.2.0 version.  I'm using 3.0 preview.  I can't install a previous version as there are other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it, not the best way, but it works.  I decided to make the library targeted specifically for .NET Core 3.0.  So, I changed the targetframework in the project file.  That change automatically resolved my other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Import the [Microsoft.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore/) package, and use [`WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()`](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L148) instead.  According to the code it is built from, both [`CreateDefaultBuilder()`](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L148) and [`ConfigureWebHostDefaults()`](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/GenericHostBuilderExtensions.cs) call the same internal method: [`ConfigureWebDefaults()`](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/d417aacd7c0eff202f7860fe1e686aa5beeedad7/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L201).

The only downside of this is that the returned host will be an IWebHost instead of an IHost.